# jQuery plugins not working with Knockout

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

I'm new to Knockout but have been using jQuery for quite a while. In a project I'm currently working on, we're using Knockout view models.

However, we also use a couple of jQuery plugins for tabs, overlays, etc. These all work fine when KO isn't used, or when used outside of a container with `data-bind`. For example, jQuery Tools' Overlay plugin doesn't work when the trigger is placed inside a container bound to KO.

Here's a simple example with a jQuery event which is never triggered:

```
<div data-bind="with: dummyData">
    <a class="alert" href="#">Never fires!</a>
</div>
<div>
    <a class="alert" href="#">Works!</a><br /><br />
    <a href="#" data-bind="click: $root.showHidden">Show hidden link.</a>
</div>
```

And here's the JavaScript:

```
var myViewModel = function () {
    var self = this;
    self.dummyData = ko.observable(false);

    self.showHidden = function () {
        self.dummyData(true);
    };
};

ko.applyBindings(new myViewModel());

$(document).ready(function () {
    $('a.alert').click(function () { alert('Clicked!'); });
});
```

Does KO replace the first container with different content or update the DOM so the jQuery click event doesn't work anymore?

I know that KO has its own `click:` event. I use this often, but right now I would simply like to know whether it is still possible to bind click events with jQuery, particularly because I would like to use this with some jQuery plugins that bind themselves on an object's click event.

Comment: Your code works for me. Here is fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/fGX3d/1/

Comment: Sorry, yes, that works. I've updated your fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/fGX3d/2/. Click the 'Show hidden' link and the jQuery event on the hidden <a class="alert"> never fires...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [jquery.live](http://api.jquery.com/live/) to bind click event:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('a.alert').live('click', function () {
        alert('Clicked!');
    });
});
```

Here is working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/fGX3d/3/

Comment: Just as a quick addendum, jQuery has deprecated `.live` in favor of using [`.on`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) with a parent selector argument. Artem's answer still works, it's just not the recommended style. So instead of `$('a.alert').live('click'` you'd say `$('body').on('a.alert','click'`.

Answer (score 4):

Under the hood, KnockoutJS considers the `with` binding to be a special case of the `template` binding! Every descendent of the `<div data-bind="with: dummyData">` is being deleted and recreated every time an observable in the viewmodel changes, and when those DOM elements are deleted your jQuery handlers are too. Using `.on` at a level higher than your template binding is one way of getting around this. The Knockout `click` binding seems like a better choice to me, though.